# Short Answer Submission Using Google Classroom API

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

I am trying to `SHORT_ANSWER_SUBMISSION` for an `coursework` via Google Classroom API.

For an patch request for a course the user must be under the same domain and have to have permission for edit content. All criteria has been fulfilled.

Coursework is posted by teacher@domain.com and `SHORT_ANSWER_SUBMISSION` is done from student@domain.com

but it returns

```
        "status": 500,
        "type": "Google_Service_Exception",
        "messages": [
            "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"updateMask: updateMask may only contain \\\"draftGrade\\\" or \\\"assignedGrade\\\".\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"updateMask: updateMask may only contain \\\"draftGrade\\\" or \\\"assignedGrade\\\".\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"badRequest\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n  }\n}\n"
        ]
    }
```

Which should given, when teacher submit assigedGrade or draftGrade via same api

this is my submission object

```
Google_Service_Classroom_StudentSubmission {#1362
  #collection_key: "submissionHistory"
  +alternateLink: null
  +assignedGrade: null
  #assignmentSubmissionType: "Google_Service_Classroom_AssignmentSubmission"
  #assignmentSubmissionDataType: ""
  +associatedWithDeveloper: null
  +courseId: null
  +courseWorkId: null
  +courseWorkType: null
  +creationTime: null
  +draftGrade: null
  +id: null
  +late: null
  #multipleChoiceSubmissionType: "Google_Service_Classroom_MultipleChoiceSubmission"
  #multipleChoiceSubmissionDataType: ""
  #shortAnswerSubmissionType: "Google_Service_Classroom_ShortAnswerSubmission"
  #shortAnswerSubmissionDataType: ""
  +state: null
  #submissionHistoryType: "Google_Service_Classroom_SubmissionHistory"
  #submissionHistoryDataType: "array"
  +updateTime: null
  +userId: null
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: []
  #processed: []
  +"shortAnswerSubmission": Google_Service_Classroom_ShortAnswerSubmission {#1363
    +answer: "abc"
    #internal_gapi_mappings: []
    #modelData: []
    #processed: []
  }
}
```

And i used this method

```
$data = $request->all();
$client = setGoogleClient(getOAuthToken());
        $class = new \Google_Service_Classroom($client);
$submission = setShortAnswerSubmission($data);
$response = $class->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->patch($courseId, $courseWorkId, $id, $submission);
```

How to submit `SHORT_ANSWER_SUBMISSION` via google classroom API. is it possible?? Couldn't find any other than this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Classroom API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch#query-parameters):

> **`updateMask`** > Mask that identifies which fields on the student submission to update. This field is required to do an update. The update fails if invalid fields are specified.

Therefore, the error message you are receiving is **self-explanatory**.

If you want to perform a `PATCH` request, the submission object should contain either `draftGrade` or `assignedGrade` but not **both**.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch).

Comment: I know, when teacher update grade i have to use draftGrade and assignedGrade in updateMask

But I want to submit short answer via a student account/id, in this case this update mask requirement shouldn't asked

Comment: If you want to submit an assignment you shouldn't be using a `patch` request to update a submission - you should be using a `post` request like this one [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn).

Comment: I want to submit 'SHORT_ANSWER_SUBMISSION'

Answer (score 0):

Answering short-answer questions is currently not exposed in the google classroom api: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155218358